# Email not triggering on redirect to page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a form that triggers an email on submit but I want to redirect it to a different page on submit.

At the moment the email only comes through with the following (i.e reloading the same page):

```
<form id="customisesystem" name="enquiry" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);" method="POST" action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
```

I want to change this to the following:

```
<form id="customisesystem" name="enquiry" onsubmit="return formCheck(this);" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/thank-you">
```

This however doesn't trigger the email.

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

This is the script that sends the email.

```
<? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

$to = "rob@domain.com";
$header = 'From: admin@domain.com';
$subject = "Quotation";
$enquiry_first_name = $_POST['enquiryfirstname'];
$enquiry_last_name = $_POST['enquirylastname'];
$enquiry_title = $_POST['enquirytitle'];
$enquiry_organisation = $_POST['enquiryorganisation'];
$enquiry_address = $_POST['enquiryaddress'];
$enquiry_country = $_POST['enquirycountry'];
$enquiry_email_address = $_POST['enquiryemailaddress'];
$enquiry_telephone = $_POST['enquirytelephone'];
$enquiry_additional_comments = $_POST['enquiryadditionalcomments'];
$enquiry_product = get_the_title();
if(!empty($_POST['hardware'])) {
    foreach($_POST['hardware'] as $check) {
        $hardwareresults .= $check."\n";
    }
}
if(!empty($_POST['systems'])) {
    foreach($_POST['systems'] as $check) {
        $systemsresults .= $check."\n";
    }
}
$productresults = "";
$quantities = array_combine($_POST['product'], $_POST['quantity']);
foreach ($quantities as $product => $quantity) {
    if ($quantity > 0) {
        $productresults .= "$quantity x $product \n";
    }
}


$body = "You have a quote request from the website:

Name: $enquiry_title $enquiry_first_name $enquiry_last_name
Type of organisation: $enquiry_organisation 
Address: $enquiry_address, $enquiry_country
E-Mail: $enquiry_email_address 
Tel: $enquiry_telephone
Comments: $enquiry_additional_comments

Send more information on:
$systemsresults

Quotation:
$enquiry_product

Hardware:
$hardwareresults

Accessories:
$productresults 

Kind regards";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);

echo "Thank you for your enquiry.";

} ?>
```

Comment: Show your js action (formCheck) please

Comment: where is you php code for sending the on thank you page or the same form page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep using the `<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>` which sends an email

and after the email code where you have used echo `"Thank you for your enquiry.";` replace it with

```
header('location: ' . bloginfo('url') . '/thank-you');
```

**EDIT**

To get posted data inside thank you page, you should pass that data from mail page.

There are 2 ways you can send data on other page in this situation

1. Use get methods. `/thank-you/?name=ABC&age=xyz
2. Store the values in session and access them on session page

**EDIT**

Try something like this

```
header('location: http://www.yourblog.com/thank-you/?title=' . $enquiry_title);
```

and in Thank you page, get that into a variable, and then echo that variable where you want to display it.

```
<?php
$title = $_GET['title'];
...
?> Thank you message and your HTML structure
 Your message titled: <b> <?php echo $title; ?> </b> is received. we will contact you shortly
.... blah blah
```

I hope this make some sense.

Comment: It's not actually picking up `bloginfo('url')`, is the syntax wrong? It's just reading the thank-you part, the redirection and sending works though.

Comment: if the page is outside the blog's scope means the blog files are not included in mail php page then it will not go to bloginfo('url'). you need to have the URL in mail page someway

Comment: Ok no problem, I can hard code it. Is there no way to use the action of the form? The thank you page has something things that are reliant on the post data, which no longer works using your method.

Comment: well, if you need posted data in thank you page. check my updated answer

Comment: Sessions are notoriously difficult to get to work in Wordpress. The thank you page only needs to grab the title so is there a way to use Get just for that one variable and pass it to the thank you page?

Comment: @Rob Please check my updated post for passing enquqery_title to thank-you page.

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal because you do not send any info to your email script. To redirect your clients to another page after email has been sent you must send propper HTTP header to user agent.
You can achieve this by adding this code to **last line of your email script** (do not change action in submit form):

```
header ( "Location: " . bloginfo('url') . "/thank-you" );
```

this will redirect user to another page after mail sending process is over.

**EDIT**

As "Aamir Mahmood" already mentioned you can pass title in the URL query string like this:

```
header ( "Location: http://some.site.com/foo/bar/thank-you/?title=$enquery_title");
```

and in thank-you page just do like this:

```
$title = $_GET["title"];
# use $title as you need
```

I hop this helps

Comment: It's not actually picking up `bloginfo('url')`, is the syntax wrong? It's just reading the thank-you part, the redirection and sending works though.